# AngularJS Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, dynamic-forms, dynamicform

I have a function for Dynamic form like this

```
$scope.ProdLinkFormData = {};
$scope.ProdLinkFormData.link = [{
  link: null,
  price: null,
  priceType: null,
  category: null
}, {
  link: null,
  price: null,
  priceType: null,
  category: null
}];
$scope.addLinkItem = function() {
  $scope.ProdLinkFormData.link.push({
    link: null,
    price: null,
    priceType: null,
    category: null
  });
};

$scope.removeLinkItem = function(linkItem) {
  //console.log(subscriber);
  $scope.ProdLinkFormData.link.pop(linkItem);
};
```

My view contains something like this

```
<div id="web" ng-repeat="linkItem in ProdLinkFormData.link">
  <div class="row col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-6 control-label">*Category: </label>
        <select class="pull-left" id="prodLinkCategory" name="prodLinkCategory" ng-required="true" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].category" required/>
        <option ng-repeat="item in scpProdLinkCat" value="{{item.prodlink_category_value}}" ng-selected="prodLinkNew[$index].category==item.prodlink_category_value">{{item.prodlink_category_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Price (optional): </label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <select class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" name="price" id="price" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].price_type">
              <option ng-repeat="item in scpPriceType" value="{{item.pricetype_name}}">{{item.pricetype_name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <input type="number" class="col-md-1 input-group inline form-control" name="price" id="price" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].price" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" / ng-value="prodLinkNew[$index].price">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-6 control-label">*Product Link EC: </label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodEC" ng-required="true" id="prodEC" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].Productlink_EC" required/>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It displays accordingly but my problem is that if I have two data on the database, only one data will be displayed on the form on page load and the second one will be displayed only after I add another from. How can I display the two data simultaneously?

Comment: Show your view and the full controller definition ideally insert a running script.

Comment: @shaunhusain edited my question, added my view

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('mainApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.ProdLinkFormData = {};
    $scope.ProdLinkFormData.link = [
            { link: null, price: null, priceType: null, category: null },
            { link: null, price: null, priceType: null, category: null }
    ];
    $scope.addLinkItem = function() {
            $scope.ProdLinkFormData.link.push({ link: null, price: null, priceType: null, category: null });
    };

    $scope.removeLinkItem = function(linkItem) {
        //console.log(subscriber);
        $scope.ProdLinkFormData.link.pop(linkItem);
    };

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div id="web" ng-repeat="linkItem in ProdLinkFormData.link">
<div class="row col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<br/><br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-6 control-label">*Category: </label>
    <select class="pull-left" id="prodLinkCategory" name="prodLinkCategory" ng-required="true" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].category" required/>
       <option ng-repeat="item in scpProdLinkCat" value="{{item.prodlink_category_value}}" ng-selected="prodLinkNew[$index].category==item.prodlink_category_value">{{item.prodlink_category_name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-6 control-label">Price (optional): </label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<select class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" name="price" id="price" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].price_type">
    <option ng-repeat="item in scpPriceType" value="{{item.pricetype_name}}">{{item.pricetype_name}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
<input type="number" class="col-md-1 input-group inline form-control" name="price" id="price" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].price" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"/ ng-value="prodLinkNew[$index].price">
</div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-6 control-label">*Product Link EC: </label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodEC" ng-required="true" id="prodEC" ng-model="prodLinkNew[$index].Productlink_EC" required/>

</div>
</div>
</div>
    <br/><br/>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
    </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Just copied and pasted your code and added a module around it and it loads two entries into the view for the ng-repeat as expected.

Verify your data coming back from the server paste it here if you'd like for what gets populated into the link property array.

Comment: yah, it displays two entries into the view but my problem is for example, it has three data from the database, the third entry will only be displayed if I added another entry

Comment: @bleykFaust need to see an example of the actual problem... if it has to do with how you get or insert the data into the data model that isn't shown here so not sure what else anyone could do?

Comment: Im fetchingdata from the database through API I have several data but I cant display it all on first load only one form

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question

1. at first you have a new array from api for example has 2 object
2. 2nd you want to show first form
3. when you click on add, should added the 2nd form
4. this example is dynamic you can add `n` object in `apiArray`

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.apiArray = [
        {
            num: 1,
        },
        {
            num: 2,
        }];
    //create new model
    $scope.newArray = [];
    
    $scope.newArray.push($scope.apiArray[0]);
    
    $scope.add = function () {
        var apiArrayLength = $scope.apiArray.length - 1;
        var newArrLength = $scope.newArray.length - 1;
        if (newArrLength < apiArrayLength) {
            $scope.newArray.push($scope.apiArray[newArrLength + 1])
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <b>apiArray</b> length is {{apiArray.length}}, we can add just {{apiArray.length}} form in <b>newArray</b>, form 1 is default added to newArray
    </div>
    <button ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="linkItem in newArray">
      <div class="well">
        form {{linkItem.num}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```